# NodeJs - Is there a way to limit number of call/tries that are made when trying to connect to a remote server using await & Promise

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So I am facing a issue where in I am trying to connect to a remote server in Nodejs using async, await and Promise.

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.1.239.44:80
     at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
     at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
```

The issue is that when the server is unavailable and above error occurs, instead of returning the status, my request keeps trying to connect to the server periodically as seen below -

```
  Do the POST call
  ERROR>>>>Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.1.239.44:80
  Do the POST call
  ERROR>>>>Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.1.239.44:80
  Do the POST call
  ERROR>>>>Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.1.239.44:80
  Do the POST call
  ERROR>>>>Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.1.239.44:80
  Do the POST call
  ERROR>>>>Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.1.239.44:80
```

Below is my code snippet

Front end (Reactjs)-

```
submit = async() => {
this.spinner("show");

var fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');

if(fileInput.files.length === 0){
    alert("Select at least one file to upload.");
}else{
    for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
        const upDoc = await this.uploadDocument(fileInput.files[i].name)
      .then(document => {
        this.setState({ document: document.document })
        this.displayDocumentInfo();

        this.spinner("hide");
        this.reload();
        this.setState({ uploaded: !this.state.uploaded });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.spinner("hide");
        alert(err);
        console.log("ERROR111>>>>"+err);
      });

      console.log("NI Nmber>>>"+this.state.document["NI Number"]);

    }
}
}
```

Back end(NodeJs) -

```
 app.get('/uploadDocument/:appId/:file', async (req, res)  => {
     var document  = await datacapconnection.uploadDocument(req.params.file,req.params.appId)
                      .then(document =>{
                        console.log("DOCUMENT >>> "+JSON.stringify(document));
                        var jsondata = JSON.parse(document);

                        if(jsondata.hasOwnProperty('DocId')){
                          var docId = jsondata.DocId;
                          var financeInfo  = dbconnection.saveFinacialInfo(document);
                          console.log("Finance Info >>>"+JSON.stringify(financeInfo));
                          var docInfo = dbconnection.insertDocumentInfo(docId,req.params.appId,req.params.file);
                        }

                        res.json({ document: JSON.parse(document) });
                      })
                      .catch((err) => {console.log("ERROR>>>>"+err)});
});
```

From the above code I am able to get the error from the function **datacapconnection.uploadDocument** and print it in the **catch** block.

```
 const express = require('express');
 var http = require('http');

 const app = express();
 var request = require('request');

 var FormData = require('form-data');
 var fs = require('fs');

 const dirName = 'C:\\Users\\abhinav.a.mehrotra\\Desktop\\DataCap\\PaySlips\\';

var uploadDocument = function(file, appId){

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{

   jsonObject = JSON.stringify({
    "file" : file
});

var postheaders = {
  'Content-Type' : 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyrV7KO0BoCBuDbTL'
};

const formData = {
  file: fs.createReadStream(dirName + file),
};

var payload = {
  url: 'http://10.1.239.45/datacapture/fn/digidocs/submitAsTransaction/'+appId,
  formData: formData,
  headers: postheaders
}

console.log('Do the POST call');

var proxyRequest = request.post(payload, function(err,res,body) {
  if(err){
    reject(err);
    return
  }


      resolve(body);
});
 })
}

 exports.uploadDocument = uploadDocument;
```

How can i make sure that only one call goes out. If there is any error it returns to my front end rather than keep waiting for the connection to happen. Any Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `res.status(500).json({success: false})` or something similar in the catch block (on server-side)? I can see that you are not returning a response which is causing the request to not return anything.

Comment: @NishantGhodke I have added the code for uploadDocument function. As you can see i am resolving the body when it is success but when it is an error it rejects the error. Is that what you meant in the above comment?

Comment: Even if its an error, let your react app know that something is wrong on the server side. To do that, try sending response ie. `res.json` from the catch block.

Comment: Did that.. thanks solved my issue :)

Comment: You're welcome, Abhinav. I have added my response as an answer to this question. Please accept it as a solution to encourage contributors like me and you to help this community.

Answer (score 0):

To complete a request cycle, you have to send the response at some point. In your case, when its an error-- all you do is `console.log` which prints the error. I am unsure why it repeat the errors though, a `watcher` (nodemon) might be the possible reason.

The solution to your query is to send response whenever your function comes to a conclusion, it could be a positive or a negative response. Add the follwing line in your `catch` block to indicate that the request has failed:

```
// some process
.catch(function(error) {
  res.status(500)
     .json({
        success: false,
        message: typeof error.message && error.message === "string" ? error.message: "Technical error! Please contact support."
     })
})
```